# Prevent Vite.js from renaming javascript variables (keep originally declared variable names)

Tags: javascript, devops, vite, alpine.js, esbuild

I'm looking to get Vite.js to **not** rename javascript variable names because I'm referencing these in my HTML DOM via Alpine-js. I understand that this is inherently part of the Vite's build method.

One solution is to prevent minification using the following:

```
build: {
    minify: 'none',
  }
```

However, this is preventing **ALL** the minification benefits of Vite and that is not what I want. I would still love to utilise JavaScript minification **and** keep the variable names as they have been originally declared.

If I need to provide you with more details please let me know and I will update the question.

Many thanks in advance!

Comment: https://esbuild.github.io/api/#minify

Comment: Thank you @Teemu - However I do not see anything to prevent the renaming of variables during minification. Please could you provide further references?

Comment: I'm not familiar with this, but there's "_--minify-identifiers_", you've to configure Eslint by removing that directive/setting it false.

Comment: @Teemu thanks but I don't like that documentation works with Vite config

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you can do this workaround :

```
build: {
    minify: 'terser',
    terserOptions: {
    compress: {
        keep_fnames: /^.*/, // Use a regular expression to match all function names
    },
    },
},
```

or in the keep_fnames you can add the variable names you want to add according to [terser build documentation](https://terser.org/docs/api-reference/#minify-options)

```
build: {
    minify: 'terser',
    terserOptions: {
    compress: {
        keep_fnames: ["variableName"] // add rest of variables you want to execlude
    },
    },
},
```

Comment: Wow, Thanks Mo! I will see if this works for me.